# a Method to find Common integers between 2 arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to write a **method** to find the commons between 2 arrays in C# but the thing is I can't convert my python logic from the past to C#
it used to be like this in python:

```
def commonfinder(list1, list2):
commonlist = []
for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        if x==y:
            commonlist.append(x)
            
return commonlist
```

but when I tried to convert it to C#:

```
        public int [] Commons(int[] ar1, int[] ar2)
        {
            int commoncount;
            int[] Commonslist = new int[commoncount];
            
            foreach (int x in ar1)
            { 
                foreach (int y in ar2)
                {
                    if (x == y)
                    {
                        commoncount++;
                        // here I should add x to Commonlist
                    }
                }
            }

            return Commonslist;
        }
```

I couldn't find any method or functions that would append x to my Commonlist
and ofc I got a lot of errors I couldn't solve
can I get a tip?

Comment: You can use a [`List<int>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0) and the method [`.Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Commoncount will be initialized with zero. So you will have a very short array in the beginning. If you try to convert the code to c# you should use the proper tools that C# offers. Use an extensible collection like List

Comment: How about just `return ar1.Intersect(ar2).ToArray();` ?

Comment: Can't believe I forgot about `Intersect`. Interested to know the computational and memory complexity of it here though.

Comment: What assumptions do you have about input.
1. Are there any possible duplicates values in each array?
2. How do you want to handle duplicates in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original algorithm has `O(n * m)` time complexity, which can be *too long*:
imagine that you have lists of 1 million items each (1 *trillion* compares to perform). You can implement a better code with `O(n + m)` complexity only:

**Code:** (let's *generalize* the problem)

```
using System.Linq;

...

public static T[] CommonFinder<T>(IEnumerable<T> left, 
                                  IEnumerable<T> right,
                                  IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null) {
  if (null == left || null == right)
    return new T[0]; // Or throw ArgumentNullException exception

  comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

  Dictionary<T, int> dict = right
    .GroupBy(item => item)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());

  List<T> result = new List<T>();

  foreach (T item in left)
    if (dict.TryGetValue(item, out int count)) {
      result.Add(item);

      if (count <= 1)
        dict.Remove(item);
      else
        dict[item] = count - 1;
    }

  return result.ToArray();
}
```

**Demo:**

```
int[] left  = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] right = new int[] { 0, 3, 2, 6, 9};

var common = CommonFinder(left, right);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", common));
```

**Outcome:**

```
2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: What I understood is you want a method that takes 2 int arrays and yields 1 int array as the output with the unique intersecting values.

You can use `HashSet` to speed up to insert and lookup time `(amortized O(1))`. The running time is `O(Max(n,m))` due to us having to go through both the entire arrays (separately). In terms of memory, `O(Min(n,m))` because we select the smaller array at the beginning to populate the set and for the rest of the logic naturally won't have more elements than the smaller array because it is the intersect.

The `Main` method shows you how to utilize the method. `CommonIntegers` has the logic which you seek.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestCode.StackOverflow
{
    public class So66935672
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] intArray1 = new int[] { 9, 9, 1, 3, 5, 6, 10, 9 };
            int[] intArray2 = new int[] { 19, 17, 16, 5, 1, 6 };

            Console.Write(
                CommonIntegers(intArray1, intArray2)
                    .Select(i => $"{i}, ")
                    .Aggregate(string.Empty, string.Concat));

        }

        private static int[] CommonIntegers(int[] intArray1, int[] intArray2)
        {
            if (intArray1 == null || intArray1.Length == 0
                || intArray2 == null || intArray2.Length == 0)
            {
                return Array.Empty<int>();
            }

            var primaryArraySet = new HashSet<int>(); // Contains the unique values from the shorter array
            var intersectSet = new HashSet<int>(); // Contains unique values found in both arrays

            int[] secondarySet;

            // Fill primary set
            if (intArray1.Length > intArray2.Length)
            {
                foreach (var i in intArray2)
                    primaryArraySet.Add(i);

                secondarySet = intArray1;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var i in intArray1)
                    primaryArraySet.Add(i);

                secondarySet = intArray2;
            }

            // Fill intersect array
            foreach (var i in secondarySet)
                if (primaryArraySet.Contains(i))
                    intersectSet.Add(i);

            return intersectSet.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
static List<int> CommonFinder(List<int> list1, List<int> list2)
{
    List<int> commonList = new List<int>();
    foreach (int x in list1)
        foreach (int y in list2)
            if (x == y)
                commonList.Add(x);
    return commonList;
}

static void Main()
{
    List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 2, 3, 4};

    var common = CommonFinder(list1, list2);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", common));
}
```